# PopupMenu compatibility for Gingerbread

Tags: android, popupmenu

I adapted PopupMenu source for Gingerbread compatibility using original PopupMenu Android source and ActionBarSherlock.
The problem is that popup menu has transparent background and small font.
I tried to specify a style in theme (Widget.Sherlock.PopupMenu) or to pass a themed context (using ContextWrapper) but it won't be styled. Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Newest Android compatibility library introduced PopupMenu and it works as it should